# Oracle Linux: Metadata file does not match checksum

Tags: linux, yum

I am facing this issue : Metadata file does not match checksum while am doing - yum update

I followed every step of this link but yet it fails:

- https://community.oracle.com/thread/2550364

I have even tried the following

- yum clean metadata
- adding this line in /etc/yum.conf file - http_caching=none

None of this seems to work.

I am getting the following error while updating

```
    # yum update
    Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security, ulninfo
    Setting up Update Process
    cloudera-cdh5                                                                                                                                    |  951 B     00:00     
    cloudera-cdh5/primary                                                                                                                            |  43 kB     00:00     
    cloudera-cdh5                                                                                                                                                   146/146
    cloudera-manager                                                                                                                                 |  951 B     00:00     
    cloudera-manager/primary                                                                                                                         | 4.1 kB     00:00     
    cloudera-manager                                                                                                                                                    7/7
    public_ol6_UEKR4                                                                                                                                 | 1.2 kB     00:00     
    public_ol6_UEKR4/primary                                                                                                                         | 1.9 kB     00:00     
    http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/UEKR4/x86_64/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum
    Trying other mirror.
    public_ol6_UEKR4/primary                                                                                                                         | 1.9 kB     00:00     
    http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL6/UEKR4/x86_64/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum
    Trying other mirror.
    Error: failure: repodata/primary.xml.gz from public_ol6_UEKR4: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Answer (score 1):

The workaround to make it works is cleaning your yum cache.

```
# yum clean all
```